# How to update Geth on Ubuntu without using the PPA

Tags: go-ethereum, homestead, linux, installation, ubuntu

I originally downloaded Geth using the instructions on the original (read: old) Ethereum homepage, using a `curl` command in a Bash one-liner. I now want to update to a version that will support Homestead.

The [current Ubuntu installation instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu) are based on `apt-get`, which pulls things from the official repository.

Is there any way I can update without moving to using the repository method? If I *do* now have to use the repository method, how do I remove the old version of Geth without losing my account data?

Comment: I'm not sure about all the details for removing it.  But you will not lose you account information as long as you simply make a backup copy of the information located in the keystore directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Building Geth (command line client)

Clone the repository to a directory of your choosing:

`git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum`

Install latest distribution of Go (v1.4) if you don't have it already:

Building geth requires some external libraries to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libgmp3-dev golang
```

Finally, build the geth program using the following command.

```
cd go-ethereum
make geth
```

#### Updating

```
cd go-ethereum
git pull
make geth
```

from the [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu)

Comment: I have faced with following error/warning: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/33087/4575. How could I overcome it? @niksmac

Answer (score 4):

You can compile yourself and avoid the repository.

The detailed instructions are [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu)

A quick summary of the building process is:

1. Clone the repo:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
   ```
2. Install dependencies.
3. Build the software:

   ```
   cd go-ethereum && make geth
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The bash script you used to install added the repository key to your local keyring and updated your sources. Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and have a look at what's there, you'll find ethereum.

As for your concerns about losing your account data when you upgrade or reinstall, you needn't worry. First, because you will (obviously, right?) back up all your app data anyway, at least your keystore folder. And second, because the application data directory is not removed or altered by you upgrading or reinstalling the application. The data directory for geth (on linux) is in a hidden folder `~/.ethereum`. Use `Ctrl+h` in file manager if you want to access via GUI.