# How to upgrade geth to version 1.7.3?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to update `geth`. I have followed this guide: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2088/4575

When I do: `git pull`: I have face with following error.

```
From https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
   dd06c8584..e7610eadf  master      -> origin/master
   021c3c281..ab5646c53  release/1.6 -> origin/release/1.6
 * [new branch]          release/1.7 -> origin/release/1.7
 * [new tag]             v1.6.7      -> v1.6.7
 * [new tag]             v1.7.3      -> v1.7.3
 * [new tag]             v1.6.2      -> v1.6.2
 * [new tag]             v1.6.3      -> v1.6.3
 * [new tag]             v1.6.4      -> v1.6.4
 * [new tag]             v1.6.5      -> v1.6.5
 * [new tag]             v1.6.6      -> v1.6.6
 * [new tag]             v1.7.0      -> v1.7.0
 * [new tag]             v1.7.1      -> v1.7.1
 * [new tag]             v1.7.2      -> v1.7.2
You are not currently on a branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
```

**[Q]** What should I do to overcome this error? Please note that I am not well experience on git, sorry about that.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: Unless you've made changes to the code and built the executable yourself, you might just be better downloading the new executable from the Downloads page, and overwriting the old `/usr/bin/geth` (i.e. just copy the new one over the top). https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/

Comment: I have tried `git pull origin master` but it pulled version 1.8.0 unstable. @Richard Horrocks

Comment: [How come you are not on any branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25670173/827525) and this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4735556/827525)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are unfamiliar ith `git` and `make` you should perhaps consider installing a binary directly. Go to https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ and click on the "Geth 1.7.3 for macOS" button. (Or whatever the most recent stable version is.)

Another altogether more manageable process would be to use [homebrew](https://brew.sh).